# How to configure Jest to run tests that have a certain suffix

Tags: regex, jestjs

I am trying to configure Jest in my project.
I would like to run tests that are in directory `__tests__` but only have the `-test` or `-spec` suffix

I tried `(/__tests__/.*|\\.(-test|-spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$` however it seems to run all files under my `__test__` directory

The fix is probably something very simple but I'm not good with regex

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the test regex is a little bit weird because you have to do double escape backslashes for regexes in json strings.

In Jest 19+, you can do this using `testMatch` instead.

```
{
  ...
  testMatch: "**/__tests__/+([a-zA-Z0-9_-])-@(test|spec).@(js|ts|tsx)"
  ...
}
```